# Select and insert by keeping references to original data in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I am exploring graphDB query languages. At the moment looking at [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/orientdb/) query language. I would like to see how a transaction would look like in OrientDB with the following structure:

Suppose, I have two vertices, **A** and **QA**:

```
CREATE CLASS A EXTENDS V

CREATE CLASS QA EXTENDS V
```

Class A has a property called p1 of Integer:

```
CREATE PROPERTY A.p1 integer
```

Assume that A has three records  called `a1,a2,a3` with their corresponding values for p1 are `a1.p1=2; a2.p1=5; a3.p1=10;`:

```
INSERT INTO A SET p1 = 2            // call this a1
     Created record with RID #11:1   
INSERT INTO A SET p1 = 5            // call this a2
      Created record with RID #11:2   
INSERT INTO A SET p1 = 10           // call this a3
      Created record with RID #11:3
```

And assume that I have an edge called **isA** from QA to A.

```
CREATE CLASS isA EXTENDS E    // it seems that I can not restrict isA records to connect only QA records to A
```

*I would like to see how the following transaction would look like in OrientDB:*

**first:** `select all A's content where p1 < 6` => so I will get {a1,a2}

**second:** `for each element in the first query create an element in QA` => so I will get for example {qa1,qa2}

**third**: `Add records to isA Edge such that they connect elements in QA to their corresponding elements in A;` =>so, for example connect qa1 to a1 and qa2 to a2.

It seems all three queries are inter-related.

**My 1th Question:** how the above transaction (i.e., set of inter-related queries)  would look like in OrientDB?

Note that elements of A are dynamic (not fixed during my system) and I would like to synch QA elements with A, whenever A's content changes by employing the above transaction; for example, if I add *a4* to A with p1=3, and run the above set of queries, I am expecting to get a new record in QA, say qa4 which is linked to *a4*.

Comment: __1st__: `SELECT FROM A WHERE p1 < 6 `
__2nd__: `INSERT INTO QA FROM SELECT FROM A WHERE p1 < 6 `
The third I don't believe it's possible using SQL.

Comment: The third one is the core of the question,  as you wrote the 1th and 2th is achievable. The third one intends to weave the 2th to the 1th somehow!

Comment: I think weaving is doable using a host language, like Scala, or Java, But I am wondering if there is anyway to do this directly using OrientDB query language?